# Add parent field to work item cards in the Taskboard

Tags: azure-devops

In [Sprint 159 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-159-update) it's now possible to [Add parent field to work item cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-159-update#add-parent-field-to-work-item-cards). This seems to work for the Boards and Backlogs but not for the Sprints/Taskboard. The parent field is not available. Is this by design or am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like it wasn't added for the taskboard. A workaround might be to add the parent column to the sprint backlog view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue, Yes, adding parent field to Taskboard card is currently not supported in azure devops.  Until now, in our official feature suggestion for Azure Devops forum, there has been a such suggestion exist in it: [Show parent on the Sprint Board Stories (not tasks)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/798483/show-parent-on-the-sprint-board-stories-not-tasks.html). You can comment and vote it there to increase priority. Our PM and Product Group are reviewing these suggestion regularly and considering take it as plan.

As a workaround, as Josh said, you can add a parent column to the Backlog of Spirit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Voted up suggestion. We are already using the workaround but we tend to use the Taskboard in our daily scrum meetings.